# Embed Magnolia content into existing web app

Tags: jsp, integration, magnolia

We're trying to embed Magnolia-managed content into some of the JSPs of an existing web app. In Tomcat we deployed and set up a "magnoliaAuthor" context that runs along our existing "app" context.

So, for example, we'd like an existing JSP such as `/app/test.jsp` to include a Magnolia page such as `/magnoliaAuthor/footer` (just a div). In the browser the path `/magnoliaAuthor/footer` renders fine, but we're facing issues when trying to include that into `/app/test.jsp` using:

- `c:import`
- `jsp:include`

and the like, with both relative and absolute paths to `/magnoliaAuthor/footer`..

At most we're getting the following:

Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: `http://localhost:8080/magnoliaAuthor/footer` (when an absolute URL is used). This seems like the request was rejected by Magnolia..

We couldn't find an exact description of how this use case should be put together. Any hint will be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Hello Daniel, I rolled back the question to its original content because your edit [radically changed the meaning of it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/108500/210583). As I understand, your original problem (`unauthorized` status code) has been solved. Feel free to ask another question with your new problem.

Comment: Ok, sorry about that, I reposted the updated question to [link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19572765). Thanks for your help.

Comment: You are welcome. By the way, if an answer has solved your problem, you can mark it as "accepted" by clicking on the ✓ mark left of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTTP 401 is **[unauthorized](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html)**:

> The request requires user authentication.

Which makes sense: The magnoliaAuthor instance **always** needs a username and password so you can login, since it is the instance where [editors work](http://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS/Instances).

What you need is sending magnoliaAuthor a username and password. My research has shown that Magnolia uses two login-filters, placed in `/server/filters/login/loginHandlers`:

- One handles [HTTP basic authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication)
- The other handles the login with the Magnolia login-form

You can make use of the HTTP basic authentication and include your Magnolia page like:

```
<c:import url="http://username:password@example.com/magnoliaAuthor/app/test" />
```

**Note:** You wrote that you have no problems including `/magnoliaAuthor/footer`. This means that your security configuration for accessing these two sites is different. You should consider checking this, usually you don't want *any* resource in magnoliaAuthor to be accessible without authorization.

Comment: Yes, you are right, the 401 response was due to not being logged into the author instance so I switched to `/magnoliaPublic/footer`, but the issue persists - I'll update the question to make it more clear. Thanks.