# Embed magnoliaPublic context content into a different web app context

Tags: jsp, integration, magnolia

We're trying to embed Magnolia-managed content into some of the JSPs of an existing web app. In Tomcat we deployed and set up a **magnoliaPublic** context that runs along our existing **app** context (i.e. two different WAR files). In the browser you can access both:

- `http://localhost:8080/app/test.jsp` and
- `http://localhost:8080/magnoliaPublic/footer`

So, for example, we'd like `/app/test.jsp` to include a Magnolia page like `/magnoliaPublic/footer` (just a div). We managed to do it by adding:

`<c:import url="http://localhost:8080/magnoliaPublic/footer" />`

to `/app/test.jsp`. This is almost fine, but a relative include would be best:

`<c:import context="/magnoliaPublic" url="/footer" />`

This latter line throws

`The requested resource (/magnoliaPublic/footer) is not available`

I suspect this is due to the way Magnolia's filter chain works, though it's set to dispatch INCLUDE and all server/filters/dispatching/* entries have toMagnoliaResources set to true.

Any hint will be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO this has nothing to do w/ Magnolia and all to do w/ how c:import works.

Did you try to verify that your request reached Magnolia's filter chain at all?

You can do so by enabling request tracking on your app server, inserting proxy in between or simply by adding `info.magnolia.debug.DumpHeadersFilter` filter in Magnolia's filter chain and observing the log.

HTH,

Jan

Comment: Indeed, I added the dump filter at the beginning of the chain and it only logs browser requests. c:import doesn't verbose anything so it doesn't hit Magnolia.

Answer (score 1):

Tomcat does not allow you to access another Servlet Context by default. I guess that is the reason why your `c:import` using the `context` attribute fails.

Tomcat has the `crossContext` attribute which configures this:

> Set to true if you want calls within this application to ServletContext.getContext() to successfully return a request dispatcher for other web applications running on this virtual host. Set to false (the default) in security conscious environments, to make getContext() always return null.

Source: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html

Enabling `crossContext` might solves your problem.